# To display the selected object properties in the table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have 2 api's called **customers** and **workers**, I am displaying all `customers`  and   `Assigned workers` of each `customer` in the `table` component like this:

[image]

Now when i click on `edit` button of particular **customer** object, I am showing that clicked object(ex Jhon Doe)  `properties` in the dialog component called `edit` like this:

[image]

Along with this, I want display assigned workers(Stephen Fluin,Micheal Swan....) properties(name,email....) in the **table component** like this:

[image]

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-sdtmzn?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)**

Comment: Since the component code is long so i gave `stackblitz link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you retrieved all your workers, you have to iterate through them:

```
public async ngOnInit() {
   this.editForm = this.fb.group({
   });
   this.selectedCustomer = this.dataService.getSelectedCustomer();
   this.workers = await this.myService.getWorkers('');
   this.customerWorkers = this.getWorkersById(this.selectedCustomer.workerIds)
}



public getWorkersById(workIds: string[]): IWorker[] {
     let workers: IWorker[] = [];
     if (this.workers && this.workers.length > 0) {
     for (const w of this.workers) {
         for(let id of workIds) {
            if(w.id == id) {
               workers.push(w);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return workers;
}
```

And set `customerWorkers` as data source of your table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="customerWorkers" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem.

**TS**

```
public async ngOnInit() {
    this.editForm = this.fb.group({
    });
     this.selectedCustomer = this.dataService.getSelectedCustomer();
     console.log(this.selectedCustomer);
     this.workers = await this.myService.getWorkers('');

     this.selectedCustomer.workerIds.forEach( id => {
       console.log(id);
       this.filteredWorker.push(this.getWorkersById(id));
     })

     this.filteredWorker = [...this.filteredWorker];
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="filteredWorker" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.email}} </td>
  </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Phone</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.phone}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

**[Forked stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-ff7bmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.ts)**

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 6, Angular provides the possibility to provide an array of objects to the Material table (called [simple table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#getting-started)) instead of a datasource class.

In your `edit.component.html`, provide your array of workers to the `datasource` directive of `mat-table`:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="workers">
```

You also don't need to create a service to communicate with your `edit.component`, because the config object in the `dialog.open()` call has a property `data` which is explicitly for this task. Please refer to the [Material dialog documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-).

---

**Update**

Based on your comment (what wasn't clear reading your initial post), you only want to show the workers of the selected customer entry.

Instead of using workers ids in your table and **then** getting the full customer object using a method, use the workers array. Pass the customer object (instead of the plain id) to the `onEdit` method in your customers.component.ts. Using the documentation for providing data to a Material dialog, you can now use the array of workers and display them in the table.

To use the worker objects instead of the plain ids, map the `this.workers` array in your `ngOnInit` method:

```
 this.customers.map((customer: ICustomer) => {
     const workers: IWorker[] = [];
     for(let i = 0; i < customer.workerIds.length; i++) {
         workers.push(getWorkerById(customer.workerIds[i]));
     }
     // You probably need a view model to assign a worker to the id field, or use `any`
     <any>customer.workerIds = workers;
 });
```

Comment: Please read my question fully, **I don't want show all worker properties**, I want show only the workers of `selected/clicked` `customer`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/loading-object-properties-into-table-gekw14?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.html

you can find your related Worker LIst in `edit.component.ts` like this:

```
console.log("this.selectedCustomer", this.selectedCustomer)
let workerlist = this.selectedCustomer.workerIds

this.workers = await this.myService.getWorkers('');
console.log("this.workers", this.workers)
for (let i of this.workers) {
  for (let j of this.selectedCustomer.workerIds) {
    if (j==i.id) {
      this.relatedWorkerLIst.push(i.name);
    }
  }
}
```

and in `edit.component.html`:

```
<form [formGroup]="editForm">
<h3>{{selectedCustomer?.name}}</h3>
<h3>{{selectedCustomer?.email}}</h3>
<h5 *ngFor="let i of relatedWorkerLIst">{{i}}</h5>
```